# Macros for copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with a Excel Macro. I need to do a macro where i am able to copy and paste as values a formula in the same row. 
I tried to do a macro but it is pasting in the wrong location. Can anyone help please!

E.g; I want to paste the formula to the right of wherever I am typing. For example, if now I am typing at A7, I will run the macro and then the formula will be pasted as values in B7

Code currently used:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
   ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image: Image shown here.]

Comment: You'll need to show the code you have so far, indicating where you're having the problem.

Comment: Can you paste in your current code sample?

Comment: I want to paste the formula to the right of wherever I am typing. For example, if now I am typing at A7, I will run the macro and then the formula will be pasted as values in B7.

Comment: When you are asked to post your code, it needs to be added to the original question and formatted correctly. Not dumped in a comment.

Comment: Oh sorry Mike.. First time posting here. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ActiveCell.Value=ActiveCell.Value
```

Comment: Which line of my code should i replace this line with?